# Need to merge two columns so I can GROUP BY in same table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make the Conversations Overview page for a messaging system in PHP/MySQL. Basically, it would look like the iPhone's Text/SMS overview page. Messages grouped by the other users you have sent or received messages from. It should show the Conversations with the newest messages (sent or received) first (descending order)

```
messages table

id | sender_id | receiver_id | datetime | message
```

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT id, sender_id, receiver_id, max( datetime ) AS dt, 
 SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( CAST( message AS CHAR )
ORDER BY datetime DESC ) , ',', 1 ) AS message
FROM vc_messages
WHERE (
 sender_id = '1'
 OR receiver_id = '1'
)
GROUP BY sender_id, receiver_id
```

The problem with the query is it doesn't GROUP BY the other user. If I sent the other user a message it shows up in the Convo overview results twice. Basically, I need to GROUP BY the sender_id and receiver_id fields.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, when you send a message the columns sender_id and receiver_id are switched compared to a message sent to you? And you need both cases within the same group?

I have no Syntax at hand, but try something along `GROUP BY MIN(sender_id, receiver_id), MAX(sender_id, receiver_id)` so that both cases will result in the same combination, no matter if sender and receiver are switched.

Comment: This return an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' receiver_id), MAX(sender_id, receiver_id)